# How can I Clear LINQ query, windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework-6

I have been working for Desktop Application Using windows form, I have been passing data between two form firm from data grid view than when the user clicks on selected row open a new form that has some controls and populate the data on it,

the problem every time the data come to the same row that populates the first time.

'''' var model = productservices.getbyId(new Guid(frmOrder.instance.productDGv.CurrentRow.Cell["ProductId"].Value.Tostring()));''''

this my query every time try to open get the same data and need to clear it when user close the form or what should I DO>>> .>

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

I Find My Error and like to share it with all.

Just I call the query in the wrong place, I modified the order of procedure then it works fine and with the right way.